# How concatenate a char with TCHAR array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, char, concatenation, tchar

I want concatenate a random string with a directory name and the final result must be something like this:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\AAAFFF1334**

On following code this part: "**AAAFFF1334**" comes strange characters see:

[image]

What must be made to fix this?

```
TCHAR mydir[MAX_PATH];

void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum)-1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}

// main

TCHAR szProgramFiles[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT hProgramFiles = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szProgramFiles);

char str;

gen_random(&str, 10);

wsprintf(mydir, TEXT("%s\\%s"), szProgramFiles, str);
```

Comment: `str` is a `char` not string or `char` array.

Comment: You are only allocating 1 character for s.

Comment: How can you fit eleven characters (ten random plus terminator) in a single `char`?

Comment: Furthermore, the `"%s"` format expects a pointer to the first character of an array of character, you pass the single `char` variable. ***And*** since you're using `wsprintf` then the strings are expected to be *wide-character* strings. All in all, plenty of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in very little code.

Comment: Offtopic: It's quite unusual not to include the null terminator in the length available, as you do. More common is the other way round, so one could do: `char str[X]; gen_r(str, sizeof(str));` - as is, one would need to do `gen_r(str, sizeof(str) - 1)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gen_random` should get char array with at least 11 characters (10 for size + 1 for terminating null).

So it should be:

```
char str[10+1]; //or char str[11];
gen_random(str, 10);
```

in addition, the format string should be:  `"%s\\%hs"`, the first is `TCHAR*` type (if  UNICODE defined `wchar_t*` if not `char*`) the second is always `char*` type.

> hs, hS
>
> String. This value is always interpreted as type LPSTR, even
>   when the calling application defines Unicode.

[look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfw)

#### Note: in Microsoft documentation:

- `LPSTR` = always `char*`
- `LPWSTR` = always `wchar_t*`
- `LPTSTR` = `TCHAR*` (if UNICODE defined: `wchar_t*`, else: `char*`)